# Multiple full text indexes on same table

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table containing columns in different languages. I want make multiple full-text indexes on this table, one for every language. Is it even possible in MsSQL (Azure)? I have the following code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs  WHERE NAME = 'BlaBlaFullTextCatalog')
    CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG BlaBlaFullTextCatalog AS DEFAULT;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [IDX_c7296e1d-8cea-40f7-9204-8f017b1e14a8_tmp] ([OBJ_FreeText_de-DE] LANGUAGE 1043) KEY INDEX [PK_bbca2bbb-a84e-4bd2-b908-92c5329652a5] ON [BlaBlaFullTextCatalog]
    WITH CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [IDX_c7296e1d-8cea-40f7-9204-8f017b1e14a8_tmp] ([OBJ_FreeText_nl-NL] LANGUAGE 1043) KEY INDEX [PK_bbca2bbb-a84e-4bd2-b908-92c5329652a5] ON [BlaBlaFullTextCatalog]
    WITH CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO;

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [IDX_c7296e1d-8cea-40f7-9204-8f017b1e14a8_tmp] ENABLE;

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [IDX_c7296e1d-8cea-40f7-9204-8f017b1e14a8_tmp] START FULL POPULATION;
```

But it throws the following error:

> A full-text index for table or indexed view
>   'IDX_c7296e1d-8cea-40f7-9204-8f017b1e14a8_tmp' has already been
>   created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) -

> As per MSDN - Only one full-text index is allowed per table or indexed
>   view, and each full-text index applies to a single table or indexed
>   view.

So the error that you are getting clearly says that `IDX_c7296e1d-8cea-40f7-9204-8f017b1e14a8_tmp` object already has one full-text index (which you have created using the second `sql statement` in your code block ) and another full-text index on the same object can't be created.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have searched a long time but could not find that restriction. Well, back to the drawingboard then...

Answer (score 1):

Index names for a table need to be unique. You are using duplicate names.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but are you sure? What part of the code is wrong then?